# Using Python to find matching arrays and combine two arrays into one

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I would like to use Python to find the matching arrays of x[0] in set1 and x[0] in set2, for example such as `[4012642, 0.10869565]` in set 1 and `[4012642, 2]` in set 2. Then I would like to combine them into 1 array and divide set1[1] by set2[1], So it would become `[4012642, (2/0.10869565)]` or `[4012642, 18.40]`. I want to do this for each variable in set1 and set2 and put into a new array. Any help is greatly appreciated, sorry I may have worded this very confusingly.

```
set1 = [[4012640, 0.014925373], [4012642, 0.10869565], [4012644, 0.40298506], [4012646, 0.04477612], [4012616, 0.6264330499999999], [4012618, 1.128477924], [4012620, 0], [4012622, 0.12820514], [4012624, 0.16417910000000002], [4013328, 0.16666667], [4012626, 0.149253743], [4012658, 0], [4012628, 0.41791046], [4012630, 0.28493894000000003], [4012632, 1.999999953], [4012634, 0.08955224], [4012636, 0], [4012638, 0]]


set2 = [[4012640, 2], [4012642, 2], [4012644, 2], [4012646, 1], [4012616, 5], [4012618, 8], [4012620, 1], [4012622, 2], [4012624, 5], [4013328, 2], [4012626, 6], [4012658, 1], [4012628, 4], [4012630, 8], [4012632, 4], [4012634, 4], [4012636, 1], [4012638, 1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you consider to be "matching" arrays? In your example, it looks like they are "matching" based on the first element. I am not sure if this is what you intended or not though.

Comment: These are lists, not arrays. In Python, arrays are in numpy.

Comment: Convert `set1` to a dictionary. Then loop through `set2`, find the dictionary element whose key is the first element, and divide its value by the second element.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I preferr to use dataframe to handle this kind 'join' question

```
# build two dataframe from set1 and set2 
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['x0','x1'])
df1['x0']=[x[0] for x in set1]
df1['x1']=[x[1] for x in set1]

df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['x0','x2'])
df2['x0']=[x[0] for x in set2]
df2['x2']=[x[1] for x in set2]
```

Then call merge method in pandas to match two dataframe by column 'x0'

```
# Merge two dataframe on 'x0'
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['x0'],how='left')

# Calculate a new columnn by 'x2'/'x1'
df['values']=df['x2']/df['x1']
```

Results:

```
    x0  x1  x2  values
0   4012640 0.014925    2   134.000001
1   4012642 0.108696    2   18.400000
```